# Issue with front camera windows 8 app

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, windows-8

Hi I am badly stuck with a issue where front camera renders real preview. I need mirror like experience like we expect with front camera. How to flip a stream coming out of capture device . Or is there any other way?? My app uses videobrush to render preview. below is link for of my reference for building this app.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh708750.aspx

```
stillCamera = await PhotoCaptureDevice.OpenAsync(sensor, new Windows.Foundation.Size(640, 480));
seq = stillCamera.CreateCaptureSequence(1);
```

Please help :(

Comment: First of all, the VideoBrush and that article are in reference to the WindowsPhone. Are you making this on Windows 8 or Windows Phone 8? If you are doing it in Windows 8 as you say, then you should be using a [CaptureElement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.captureelement). Because the `CaptureElement` is a `UIElement` like any other, you should be able to do a `RotateTransform` in its `RenderTransform`, labeling the Y Axis. I don't know 100% if this will work, but it's a start.

Comment: Hi, Iam using for windows phone